# Creating a function that shows the output step by step in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

Im trying this and the code works fine. The page process the code and then shows me the result, but I dont want this. I want the page show step by step the for process, first print A, wait some time and then show AB, wait again and show ABC, etc...

```
window.onload = function() {
  var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
  var frase = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
  var spl = frase.split("");
  document.body.appendChild(parrafo);
  for(i in spl){
    var contenido = document.createTextNode(spl[i]);
      parrafo.appendChild(contenido);
      sleep(100);
    }
  }

function sleep(ms) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > ms){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setTimeout() function and wrap the `for loop` in that.
For example,

```
printStuff(spl, i) {
    var contenido = document.createTextNode(spl[i]);
      parrafo.appendChild(contenido);
      setTimeout(printStuff(spl, i++), 1000);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work, because `printStuff` will be executed immediately. I guess you meant to `setTimeout(printStuff.bind(0, spl, i++), 1000)`, or maybe `setTimeout(function() {printStuff(spl, i++);}, 1000)`.